# How to update the records using codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to update the record but I don't know why my records are not getting updated. I'm trying it but not getting the desired result. even the validation is also not working.

**Controller part**

```
public function updatedata()
{
    $id=$this->input->get('id');
    $result['data']=$this->Form_model->displayrecordsById($id);
    $this->load->view('update_records',$result);

    if($this->input->post('update'))
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('fname', 'First name', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('lname', 'Last name', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|min_length[5]|max_length[12]|is_unique[form.username]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email|is_unique[form.email]');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE)
        {
            $config['upload_path']   = './uploads/'; 
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png'; 
            $this->load->library('upload', $config);

            if($this->upload->do_upload('filename'))
            {
                $fn=$this->input->post('fname');
                $ln=$this->input->post('lname');
                $un=$this->input->post('username');
                $em=$this->input->post('email');
                $fi= $this->upload->data('file_name');
                $this->Form_model->updaterecords($fn,$ln,$un,$em,$fi,$id);
                echo 'Successfully updated your record';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the problem with your code is you never go for else part to show the error if `if` part fails, and if your validation is not working how it will go for update

Comment: sir can u edit my code and tel me please sir im trying everything from mroning but its not working please can you help me out

Comment: please sir a bit guidence would help mw

Comment: @AnbuselvanRocky thank you for your edit, I've approved it, but there were more that you could have improved (see the revision history).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following code to help you to pinpoint the error. But it is likely that you are not defining the $id...

```
public function updatedata()
{

$id=$this->input->get('id');

if($this->input->post('update'))
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('fname', 'First name', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('lname', 'Last name', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|min_length[5]|max_length[12]|is_unique[form.username]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email|is_unique[form.email]');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {

        echo validation_errors();
        exit();

    } else {

        $config['upload_path']   = './uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if($this->upload->do_upload('filename'))
        {

            $fn=$this->input->post('fname');
            $ln=$this->input->post('lname');
            $un=$this->input->post('username');
            $em=$this->input->post('email');
            $fi= $this->upload->data('file_name');

            // $id is not defined below.... you will need to define this I would imagine!

            $this->Form_model->updaterecords($fn,$ln,$un,$em,$fi,$id);
            echo 'Successfully updated your record';
            exit();

        } else {

            echo $this->upload->display_errors();
            exit();

        }

    }

}

$result['data']=$this->Form_model->displayrecordsById($id);
$this->load->view('update_records',$result);

}
```

Comment: You should now have an error... please tell me what that error is - help me to help you - provide as much information as possible!

Comment: Has your submit button even got a name attribute set to "update"? Put some breakpoints into your code in different places to see what is hit and what is not.... `die(1);`, `die(2);` etc...

Comment: sir  if i try to edit my records im getting validation errors like The Username field must contain a unique value. The Email field must contain a unique value.

Comment: Great! You have just confirmed that your code is working and catching validation errors like it should! Now do exactly like the errors say. Use a different username and email to test!

Comment: sir when i upload everything and i got successfully message as well but later i got this error  A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: id

Filename: controllers/Form.php

Line Number: 128

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\amit\application\controllers\Form.php
Line: 128
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\amit\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174814/discussion-between-webcode-ie-and-keerthi-patil).

Comment: sir i would like to tel u it did worked. but i have a little issues